# Object life cycle logging

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, spring-boot

**Is there a way to print out a list of every event associated with a given object instance in Java 8, or in Tomcat 8, or in Spring Boot?**  This would be extremely helpful in debugging.

For example, I would like to be able to specify a type and get all the objects of that type.  And I would like to be able to print out all the events that occurred with a given object, such as instantiation, property value changes, function calls, destruction, etc.

One example of a type I want to research is `HttpSession`.  If I query the current `HttpSession` as follows using `System.out.println()`:

```
HttpSession sess = request.getSession(false);
System.out.println("request.getSession(false) is: " + sess);
String sessid = sess.getId();
System.out.println("session.getId() is: "+sessid);
```

The result is the following two lines of output:

```
request.getSession(false) is: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@68b26b9
session.getId() is: D490BB6B29E66D35205578D7C1E4B3EE
```

This gives the type `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade`, the object reference `68b26b9`, and the `id` property `D490BB6B29E66D35205578D7C1E4B3EE`.

**This OP asks how to get a history log of every event that the JVM or Tomcat or Spring performs with this specific object instance `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@68b26b9`, from birth through death.  And how to get this same kind of history log for any other given object.**  Like a stack trace, but across the entire object lifecycle instead of being localized to a single event.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this using some 3rd party tools such as asm, or other runtime hackery. But generally speaking, trying to log this data would be a waste of time.

I once got asked to support a system where the person who had written it (who was a software architect, not a developer) decided that it would be a good idea to log every method call entry and exit and all the arguments passed. The system was written using the spring framework so he did this by applying an aspect to all the classes in the app.

Whilst this worked, it produced a massive log that was pretty much indecipherable and useless for debugging. Simply because it was near impossible to find what you needed in the vast volume of information produced.

A much better idea is to use a logging framework such as [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch) or [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) and target the logging at the information developers need when debugging.

Logging, IMHO is about telling a story of what is happening with a system. As an analogy, people understand *'I drove to the shops'* much easier that *'I opened the car door, sat in the seat, put the keys in, turned the key to start...'*. Finding a balance between telling the story of your app in the logs and producing too much information is a skill well worth learning.

Just for something different to think about. I've written a logging framework for iOS apps called [Story Teller](https://github.com/drekka/StoryTeller). Why I mention this is that Story Teller takes a very different approach the the *debug, warn, info*, etc logging levels that every other framework uses. It works by allowing you to log anything as a key and to then query against those keys. This allows extremely targeted logging when debugging. For example, logging everything for account number 12345. As yet though, I've not seen anything like this for Java.

Comment: You wrote a long series of comments leading up to a plug for a totally unrelated product using a different technology (not java).  People post questions because they need answers.  Placing editorial comments where an answer should go is inconsiderate of the poster's needs in asking the question.  An object is being mis-handled in a Spring app, and the result is an insidious, deeply-concealed bug.  A real answer to this OP would enable the dropped session object to be tacked to the point of drop, so that the bug could be isolated.  If you want to write a solution to that, I would appreciate it.